# Windows 10/11 and port forwarding

Tags: windows, networking, port-forwarding

**setup info:**

```
- Connection to the internet is via a Wi-Fi adapter (DHCP IP: 192.168.1.12)
- I have no problems browsing the internet using this connection.
- The app is listening to port=9000.
```

**things I tried:**

1. on my local browser, I can view the app UI via localhost:9000.
2. With 1st netsh rule (see below), I am able to access the UI via port=80 locally. Without this rule, I am getting an error on my browser (which is expected).
3. I've disabled Windows firewall and still no luck.

[image]

**What I want to now is to be able to access the UI on port=80 on but on a 2nd PC.**

I tried the 2nd netsh command (see below) and I am getting nothing on the 2nd PC.

Any ideas? Thanks

```
=> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.12
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254

=> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=9000 connectaddress=127.0.0.1
    
=> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80 listenaddress=192.168.1.12 connectport=9000 connectaddress=127.0.0.1

=> netsh interface portproxy show all

Listen on ipv4:             Connect to ipv4:

Address         Port        Address         Port
--------------- ----------  --------------- ----------
127.0.0.1       80          127.0.0.1       9000
192.168.1.12    80          127.0.0.1       9000


=> netstat -aon -p tcp
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    192.168.1.12:80        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3744
 (I've removed all netstat output which I thought were not relevant)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a stupid question : Did you check in the Windows Firewall ?

> I tried the 2nd netsh command (see below) and I am getting nothing on the 2nd PC.

What is the error message on the 2nd computer when you try to connect ? If it's a timeout, it's a firewall blocking issue. If both computers are in the same network, it only could be a Windows Firewall blocking.

Try to disable it and check again on the 2nd computer.

Comment: I've edited my original post to state that my windows firewall is already off.

Comment: Thanks, what is the error you got on the second computer ? Are computers in the same network ?